# the why of MOV command restrictions

Tags: assembly, x86, mov, restrictions

why is MOV variable,variable incorrect?
or why must we have only registers or an immediate if we use a variable as the first operand?
or why is this wrong:
MOV [x],anything except an immediate or register
how these rules are defined? 
EDIT:
I'm talking about a 8086 processor.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean as "variable". Do you mean "mX operand"?

Comment: @Griwes a variable defined in the data section

Comment: There's no such thing as "a variable" in assembly.

Comment: @Griwes then what is this: test db ? (test with unknown initial vlaue?)

Comment: It's a label referencing an address.

Comment: The OP appears to be asking why you can't use the `mov` instruction to copy data from one memory location to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x86 MOV instructions simply do not support both a load and a store in the same instruction.

You can either load from memory to a register, or store a register to memory.  If you want to copy memory to memory in one instruction you need the `MOVS` instruction, which takes two pointers and copies them.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for assembly command are defined by the processor, or more exactly by the company which produces the processor ... and by the electronic. Registers are internal to the proc, and so can be copied to or from memory in one single machine cycle. But copy from memory to another memory pass through the processor (or via a co-processor for DMA operations).